# Real Time Data Copy from Oracle DB to ADLS via Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to copy my data from my source that is Oracle DB to Sink which is ADLS Gen2 via Azure Data Factory. But I want to make this replication real time, meaning whenever their is a change in my Oracle database it should be populated in ADLS storage.
How can I achieve this via ADF? Any good suggestion?

Comment: No, we can achieve the real time data coping. It depends on you source data size and how long the copy active takes. Even with time trigger, it's need every 5min to prepare the pipeline next execution.

Comment: Hi @Ankit, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, we can achieve the real time copy with data factory. The most closet way is set the schedule trigger for your pipeline. But even with this trigger, it needs every 5min to prepare the pipeline next execution.

You can create the pipeline wit copy active or data flow active, copy the data from Oracle to ADLS Gen2. Then create a [schedule time trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#schedule-trigger) to trigger the pipeline run. The pipeline only can be triggered at least every 5 min.

Like you said, the table data changes every second, it's not a real time copy.

HTH.

Comment: Could you help with more details? I did not understand your solution. How can I achieve real time copy via schedule trigger?
Eg: Source table : Emp is getting updated every second, many records are inserted, few are updated and few are deleted every second. So how can I achieve copy for this type of scenario.

Comment: @Ankit please see my update. I said there isn't a real copy in Data Factory. We can't achieve that in Data Factory for your scenario.

Comment: Hi @Ankit, do you have any other concerns?